# Bootstrap FormHelper Country Picker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, formhelper

I am trying to implement the bootstrap [country picker select form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I2er.png) element in my form. But I don't know for some reason it doesn't work. There are no countries in the drop down list.

I have included the all the necessary files 
Bootstrap.js, css, Jquery, Formhelper.js & formhelpercountries.js

I could have given a jsfiddle link but I don't know how to add the formhelper js there I am unable to find the cdn for that.

My code

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true">
</div>
```

Attached Screenshot
There are no drop down country options in the select element. Nor the documentation is too detailed as to how to use it.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to use this plugin?

[image]?

Comment: form where are you getting your countries records?

Comment: Could you check your console for any possible errors?

Comment: Initially I thought it would be loaded from FormHelper css or js on running as shown in the example also see http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/5qy5w/1/ but now I have manually given the values in the select tag.

Comment: @underdog Your libraries load the countries just fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qy5w/85/)

Comment: Thanks @ICanHasKittenz yup the js file was faulty but still the icons not appearing. Anyways I've added manually the select statement in the bootstrap form that should work fine.